# Handling a zip of small files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a 1 gb zip file containing around 10 millon small files.
Is importing the zip file using ZipInputStream enough or will i still face the 
"Hadoop small file problem".

Also kindly mention any better approach to solve this issue. Basically i want to parse the content of each small file and do some processing over it.

Thanks

Comment: The `zip` wont cause any trouble. Because for HDFS it will appear as a single large file

Comment: I don't think Zip can be split, so you will not get parallelism.

Comment: @Donald Miner : So what do you suggest? Should i write another program to unzip the file and create a sequence file out of all the smaller file before starting my MR program?

Comment: Yeah, block-level gzip compressed sequence files work nicely. You can put the file names as the key and the contents as the value.